# Thread Safe Grid View Update in C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer

I am explaining my problem elaborately. I have a `dataGridView` in Windows main form. I have a timer which is starting when button1 is clicked. and it stops when button2 is clicked.

Now in the meantime I am calculating something and putting it in the `dataGridView`. This is a dynamic calculation. In this calculation I am using a Thread. (I am absolutely new in Threads) . I have used `Thread.Sleep(100)`  to calculate data. Now I am using a Thread.Sleep in a loop where I am calculating data of consecutive things. I want the respective order of the calculation to remain. After each iteration of the loop I am using `dataGridView.Rows.AddRange(DataGridViewRow)` to add new row with new data calculated.

But I am not getting the data in the dataGridView in the order and also it's not coming properly. It's getting blanked out sometime and coming randomly.

P.S - I am clearing the data each time when the timer interval is over.

Comment: I have used `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` I have used Thread.Sleep(100). In this meantime, some data is collected and then calculated. then I am using `dataGridView.Rows.AddRange(DataGridViewRow)` to add data to the UI. I have used ThreadSafe approach to add those by InovokeRequired.

I have used the timer(2000) interval. Now it's giving correct result. No problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been resolved. Actually you have to set the `Thread.Sleep` timer such that it gets completed before your `Windows.Forms.Timer`'s interval is over.

Comment: This particular is resolved by that one. Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access UI controls from the UI thread.

If you try to access them from other threads, you get undefined behavior as you have found.

I suggest you start by reading this free ebook: [Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Answer (score 0):

Before you attempt to update the datagridview, you need to call datagridview.InvokeRequired.
If this is true then, call Invoke passing in the delegate which you wish to execute and any data that you want to pass.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thread safe method to set Gridview.

```
class Program
{
public static List<string> ChoiceExtension = new List<string>();
static void Main()
{
    ChoiceExtension.Add("One");
    ChoiceExtension.Add("Two");
    ChoiceExtension.Add("Three");
    //Set list as gridsource
    InserttoGrid(ChoiceExtension);

}

public static void SetDataSource(object value)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Path of Extension");
        foreach (var item in value as List<string>)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { item });

        }
        ExtensionList.DataSource = dt;
    }
public static void InserttoGrid(List<string> List)
    {
        if (ChoiceExtension.Count >0)
        {

            if (this.ExtensionList.InvokeRequired)
            {
               ExtensionList.Invoke(new SetDataSourceDelegate(SetDataSource), new Object[] { List });


            }
            else
            {
                SetDataSource(List);

            }

        }
    }

}
```